# why my image keeps appearing on the same place when I try to animate it

Tags: animation, javafx, random, imageview, timeline

I want to make an image move from right to left and make the image appear on the right side of my pane randomly.The problem is that the image appears in the same place over and over again.

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;

import javafx.animation.KeyValue;

import javafx.animation.Timeline;

import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;

import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

import javafx.stage.Screen;

import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.util.Random;

public class Comet {

private static final int paneWidth = 1100;

private static final int paneHeight = 780;

private static final int cometWidth = 100;

private static final int cometHeight = 100;

private static final int duration = 3000;
private static final int delay = 1000;
private static final Random random = new Random();




public static void animateComet(ImageView imageView) {
    imageView.setFitWidth(cometWidth);
    imageView.setFitHeight(cometHeight);

    double y = random.nextDouble() * (paneHeight - cometHeight);
    imageView.setLayoutX(1100);
    imageView.setLayoutY(y);
    Rectangle2D screenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
    double rightBound = screenBounds.getWidth() - cometWidth;

    Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
    timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.setAutoReverse(false);

    KeyFrame startKeyFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(imageView.translateXProperty(),                     screenBounds.getWidth()));
    KeyFrame endKeyFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(duration), new KeyValue(imageView.translateXProperty(), -paneWidth));

    timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(startKeyFrame, endKeyFrame);

    timeline.setOnFinished(event -> {
        double newPosition = random.nextDouble() * rightBound;
        imageView.setTranslateX(newPosition);
        timeline.playFromStart();
    });

    timeline.setDelay(Duration.millis(delay));
    timeline.play();
    }
}
```

I am basically stuck here.Whatever I try,it is the same problem.I tried changing the duration,changed the random function boundaries.I am not that good with coding.So I would appreciate if someone would help me.

Comment: the node that contains the animated node is important too . If you use stackpane as parent , it 'll  always center your animated node

Comment: @GiovanniContreras Yes and no. The translate properties transform the layout position. In a stack pane, this essentially means translating works as an offset from center (or whatever alignment the child node has).

Comment: @Armand Why do you do the "randomness" in the `onFinished` handler? Right now, it seems like you try to animate the node in smoothly, then have a "jump" to a random position. Why not just have the end position be random, possibly with a dynamic duration so all nodes the same speed? Also, see if using `TranslateTransition` makes things easier for you.

Comment: It's starting from the same place because your `startKeyFrame` is the same every time. If you want it to start from a random place, the value in that frame needs to be randomized.